# JQuery Passing Array string

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to pass an array to my .each JQuery code, but it is passing just the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3,... instead of the string values.

My code to define the variable is:

```
var accessoriesCats = [ 'Beaded Accessories', 'Cufflinks', 'Flip Flops', 'Floral Accessories', 'Foot Jewelry', 'Hair Accessories', 'Hankies', 'Jewelry', 'Leg Garters', 'Purses', 'Shoe Stickers', 'Something Blue', 'Tiaras', 'Totes' ];
```

Here is my entire code:

```
    <script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("category-s/2022.htm") != -1) {
            var accessoriesCats = [ 'Beaded Accessories', 'Cufflinks', 'Flip Flops', 'Floral Accessories', 'Foot Jewelry', 'Hair Accessories', 'Hankies', 'Jewelry', 'Leg Garters', 'Purses', 'Shoe Stickers', 'Something Blue', 'Tiaras', 'Totes' ];
                $('#content_area > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody').find('a').each(function(accessoriesCats){
                            $(this).append('<span class="promo__text">' + accessoriesCats + '</span>');
                            $(this).removeClass('smalltext colors_text').addClass('subcatRollover');
            });
        }
</script>
```

Basically what I want to get with the very first .append is:

```
<span class="promo__text">Beaded Accessories</span>
```

but instead I get

```
<span class="promo__text">0</span>
```

Comment: You are not passing `accessoriesCats` array as parameter to the `.each` function. You are iterating all the `a` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("category-s/2022.htm") != -1) {
        var accessoriesCats = [ 'Beaded Accessories', 'Cufflinks', 'Flip Flops', 'Floral Accessories', 'Foot Jewelry', 'Hair Accessories', 'Hankies', 'Jewelry', 'Leg Garters', 'Purses', 'Shoe Stickers', 'Something Blue', 'Tiaras', 'Totes' ];
        $('#content_area > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody').find('a').each(function(i){
                $(this).append('<span class="promo__text">' + accessoriesCats[i] + '</span>');
                $(this).removeClass('smalltext colors_text').addClass('subcatRollover');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, the first param of `.each` on an array is the index, the second is the item (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
.each(function(index, accessoriesCats) {
                ^^^ADD INDEX
```